# jQuery - messenger like script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Probably all of you know how facebook's messenger looks and works like. I am trying to archive something similar on my page. I divided it into few steps:

**1)** Show typing animation. After some time (in my function it's 3 sec) animation disappears (you know, those bubble like dots, just like in iphones).

**2)** When animation disappears, text message is shown. It's static html element. I don't intend to make it dynamically editable with use of php.

**3)** Thrid step is made in case user reloaded site. If element is inside user's offset, then it doesn't show typing animation. Text is shown immediately.

I decided to try jQuery. I never had any experience with it, only vanilia JS.

Code is almost complete. But i don't know how to refer to index of *msgText* elements. For now, when one *bubble-chat* is visible, all elements with class *msgText* are shown. I guess that I need another loop inside first one, but I don't really know. Thanks for help!

```
    (function($) {

  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

      var $t            = $(this),
          $w            = $(window),
          viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
          viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
          _top          = $t.offset().top,
          _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
          compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
          compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };

})(jQuery);

var win = $(window);

var allMods = $(".bubble-chat");
var msgText = $(".text");        

allMods.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    el.addClass("already-visible");
    msgText.css('display', 'block');
}

    if(el.hasClass("already-visible")) { 
        el.css('display', 'none')};
})


win.scroll(function(event) {

  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("come-in"); 
      el.delay(3000);
      el.queue(function (next) { 
        $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
        msgText.css('display', 'block');
        next(); 
    });   
}});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble with solving it, but i eventualy did! Posting it so maybe someone will use it in the future.

Turns out, that display:none elements are not rendered by browsers, so you **can't** get their offset. So I had no other choice but to use opacity. I know, that it is not that pretty, but i have no other ideas. Feel free to ask
`

```
  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

      var $t            = $(this),
          $w            = $(window),
          viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
          viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
          _top          = $t.offset().top,
          _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
          compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
          compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };

})(jQuery);

var win = $(window);

var allMods = $(".bubble-chat");
var msgText = $(".text");            


allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("already-visible");
}

    if(el.hasClass("already-visible")) { 
        el.css('display', 'none')};
})

msgText.each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  if ($(this).visible(true)) {
    $(this).addClass("already-visible");
}
    if($(this).hasClass("already-visible")) { 
        $(this).css('opacity', '1')};
})


win.scroll(function(event) {

  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("come-in"); 
        el.delay(3000);
        el.queue(function (next) { 
            $(this).css('display', 'none'); 
            next(); 
        });   
    }});

    msgText.each(function(j, s) {
    var s = $(s);
    if (s.visible(true)) {
        s.addClass("come-in"); 
        s.delay(3000);
        s.queue(function (next) { 
            s.addClass("come-in"); 
            $(this).css('opacity', '1'); 
            next(); 
        });   

    }});



});
    `
```